# Overwriting function return address using buffer overflow

Tags: c, gdb, buffer, overflow

I am attempting to overwrite the return address of a function to an attacker's address using buffer overflow. Interestingly, while using this line of code to inject into the input to generate the buffer overflow into the return address (i was certain through gdb that i have hit the return address), I encounter an unique problem.

python3 -c 'print("A" * 21 + "\x62\x93\x04\x08")'

Take note the return address of interest here is 08049362.

Using gdb the result is very strange:
Program received.... ,Segmentation Fault.
0x0493c262 in ?? ()

Apparently, its due to the "93" because when I try to overflow with the following example addresses they seem fine.

"\x62\x62\x04\x08"
"\x62\x04\x04\x08"

My questions is why is there hex value "c2" that appears out of nowhere?

Comment: Where is your C code? What is your platform?

Comment: i am using linux ubuntu 20.04, standard gcc and gdb

Comment: Your C code is still missing from the question.

Comment: ya its edited in now

Comment: Your code does not compile, please post real code. You should also care about the compiler warnings you should get.

Comment: With python3 strings, hex escapes represent Unicode codepoints, so any codepoint outside of ASCII might turn out to be longer than a single byte.  You might need to use byte strings and `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick how do you get that to run on the terminal?

Comment: Manage to solve the above issue using python2 instead. Thanks @MarkPlotnick for triggering the thoughts on python strings are handled differently in version 2 and 3. Thus, the return address was successfully exploited.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.